# .htaccess redirect to oldsite subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I used to have domain say example.com now I hosted new site on this domain, but I could not properly took all the site contents to new site. So, I created subdomain oldsite.example.com and pointed it to my server ip for previous example.com. 
Everything is fine here I see my oldsite when I type oldsite.example.com. But rest of the url still refers to example.com/xxx.

All I want to redirect using .htaccess any request coming for example.com/xxx on my previous hosting server to point to oldsite.example.com/xxx.

Note : It's wordpress site.

Answer (score 0):

Putting this into the htaccess in the root folder for the `example.com` site on your old host, should achieve what you are wanting

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://oldsite.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Can you expand on that? What happens?

Comment: It still fall back to example.com in browser, so my browser shows the new site (on separate host).

Comment: is there any htaccess on the `oldsite.example.com`?

Comment: Actually I created a A entry in DNS pointing to previous host IP with subdomain oldsite.example.com, so there is no such folder called as oldsite.example.com.